# Why does clickable link get cut off when defining \href color?

Tags: hyperref

I am using `\href{}` from the `hyperref` package. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{}
\begin{document}
\href{http://google.com}{Click me!}
\end{document}
```

This results in a PDF where the entire `Click me!` line is hyperlinked. The trouble is, when I add a color option then the clickable area in the resulting PDF is extremely short.

```
\href{http://google.com}{\color{black}}{Click me!}
```

Why is this? How do I avoid this?

I don't want to change the color option in the preamble (e.g. `\hypersetup{urlcolor = black}`) because there are many other hyperlinks that I want a different color. I just want to change this one URL.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that both `\color{black}` and the string `"Click me!"` are in the second argument of `\href` -- in the same "group", to use TeX jargon. You should thus write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{}
\begin{document}
\href{http://google.com}{\color{black}Click me!}
\end{document}
```